# can't understand subquery code using where and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, subquery, where-clause

if I wanna compare sale price of each product type with the sale price of each item within corresponding product type, here is the code to get it:

```
SELECT product_type, product_name, sale_price
FROM Product AS P1
WHERE sale_price > (SELECT AVG(sale_price) 
                    FROM Product AS P2
                    WHERE P1.product_type = P2.product_type
                    GROUP BY product_type );
```

I can't understand subquery code for 'where P1.product_type = P2.product_type'. For the WHERE outside the subquery, it should be used to filter single row. However, how could it get a single result in subquery?

Comment: That GROUP BY isn't needed and can be removed. (It is also invalid because the column name product_type is abigious.)

Comment: Inner query is called a correlated subquery. It is used to returm average price of each product type returned by outer query. WHERE clause in inner subquery exists for returning only rows corresponding to current row in outer one

Answer (score 2):

The query you wanted to write:

```
SELECT product_type, product_name, sale_price
FROM Product AS P1
WHERE sale_price > (
    SELECT AVG(sale_price) 
    FROM Product AS P2
    WHERE P1.product_type = P2.product_type
);
```

This phrases as: bring all rows from `product` whose `sale_price` is greater than the average `sale_price` of products of the same type. The subquery in the `where` clause is called a *correlated subquery*, and computes the average for all rows having the same `product_type` (the `where` clause of the subquery implements the correlation).

This could also be expressed with window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select  
        p.*,
        avg(sale_price) over(partition by product_type) avg_price_by_product_type
    from product p
) t
where sale_price > avg_price_by_product_type
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running a `AVG()`, is a grouping function. This means that you get the average value for all values returned by the subquery. As you not selecting other columns, the group assumes that you group all `sales_price` rows.

And, the RDBMS knows that you have a table called `P1` from the main query and, for every line returned by the main select, the RDBMS executes the subquery comparing the result in `P1` comparing to `P2` query.